# Liquibase: Using sequence

Tags: java, oracle11g, liquibase

I am using the `InsertStatement` class and I want to pass the sequence generation code. How do I do that? I tried following, but did not work.

```
InsertStatement statement1 = new InsertStatement("saas", "OAuth2AppTemplate");
statement1.addColumnValue("id", 
    new SelectSequencesStatement("saas.seq.nextval"));
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after lot of digging into the Liquibase documentation I found it.

```
InsertStatement statement1 = new InsertStatement("saas", "OAuth2AppTemplate");
final Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
sequence.setName("saas.OAuth2AppTemplate_id_seq.nextval");
statement1.addColumnValue("id", sequence);
```

And this then generates the query appropriately.